# Javascript replace() with case-change

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there an easy way to *change* the case of a matched string with javascript?

**Example**

String : `<li>something</li>`

Regex  : `/<([\w]+)[^>]*>.*?<\/\1>/`

And what I'd like to do is replace the match $1 to all capital letters (inside the replace if possible). I'm not entirely sure when $1 is a valid match and not a string -- '$1'.toUpperCase doesn't work.

So how would I go about returning `<LI>something</li>`? The method, not the regex.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can pass the replace method a replacer function. The first argument for which is the whole match, the second will be $1. Thus:

```
mystring.replace(/<([\w]+)[^>]*>.*?<\/\1>/, function(a,x){ 
   return a.replace(x,x.toUpperCase()); 
})
```

although this form saves the extra operation by making an additional capture (should be faster but haven't checked):

```
mystring.replace(/<([\w]+)([^>]*>.*?<\/\1>)/, function(a,x,y){ 
   return ('<'+x.toUpperCase()+y); 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

easiest is probably to use a regex match and then use .toUpperCase on the match.  I modified the regex slightly to add in a second capture group

```
var str = '<li>something</li>';
var arr = /<([\w]+)([^>]*>.*?<\/)\1>/.exec(str);
str = '<' + arr[1].toUpperCase() + arr[2] + arr[1].toUpperCase() + '>';
```